# Azure Functions HTTP not triggered in the last 60 days

Tags: azure-application-insights

Using App Insights how can I write a query that shows me the azure functions that have no been executed in the last 6o days

I came up with the following but it only shows me the ones that were executed more than 60 days ago, it does not tell me if they were excuted in the last 60 days, I am trying to find the ones who have not been executed in the last 60 days so I can flag them for removal

```
requests 
| project timestamp, operation_Name, success, resultCode, duration, cloud_RoleName
//| where timestamp > ago(30d) 
| where cloud_RoleName startswith "slapi-prd"
| where success == "True" 
| where timestamp < ago(60d)
| order by timestamp desc 
| take 20
```

Comment: If the functions are not triggered, then it will not be logged. So you should define a list which contains all the functions, then compare it with the query results.

Comment: @IvanYang they will have been triggered for sure, it’s just as we progress with new versions I need know latest execution time per function so I can see which ones have old exec times and remove them

Comment: if you just want to know the latest execution time per function(not per trigger?), then it's easy to write the query.

Comment: @IvanYang yes per function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know the latest execution time per function, please use the code below:

```
requests
//please uncomment the following lines if you need them
//| where timestamp > ago(30d)
//| where cloud_RoleName startswith "slapi-prd"
//| where success == "True" 
| summarize timestamp = max(timestamp) by name, cloud_RoleName
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, this will be over function app, I need it per function, I think you called it triggers above, one function can have multiple functions, I need to know the latest exec date for each of those functions

Comment: @MattDouhan, then just add the `name` field. Updated my answer:).

Comment: this works great, but is there a limit to how far back app insights saves my data? because I am not getting all functions even if I go back years

Comment: @MattDouhan, yes, by default, the data will be kept for 90 days. But you can select a retention period up to 730days, as per [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#change-the-data-retention-period).